# missing plot title in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I create a plot title in ggplot2? Am I making a silly syntax error?

The [ggplot2 docs](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/labs.html) indicate that labs(title = 'foo') should work, but I can only get the arguments `x='foo'` and `y='foo'` to work with `labs()`. Neither `ggtitle()` nor `title()` worked either.

Here is an example.

```
x <- rnorm(10,10,1)
y <- rnorm(10,20,2)
xy.df <- data.frame(x,y)
qplot(x,y, data=xy.df, geom='point', color=x*y) + 
  labs(title = "New Plot Title",
       x='Some Data', 
       y='Some Other Data')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `main` argument in the function `qplot`:

```
qplot(x,y, data=xy.df, geom='point', color=x*y, main = "New Plot Title") + 
  labs(x='Some Data', 
       y='Some Other Data')
```

[image]

Comment: @csgillespie Yes, it worked, but only if I moved the `+` from the beginning of the second line to the end of the first (like in my answer).

Comment: Many thanks! This syntax worked. Not sure what is causing the problem with ggplot2 and the labs(title='foo') syntax. Perhaps some incompatible library is also loaded, or dependencies unsatisfied.